# Show that $d_1$ isnt norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $d_1$ be difine by $d_1:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x_1,x_2)\rightarrow (\sqrt{|x_1|} + \sqrt{|x_2|})^2$.
show that isn't norm.

Solution:
 $(\sqrt{|x_1|} + \sqrt{|x_2|})^2 =1$,
but I can not prove it is convex.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

$d_{1}(4,9)+d_{1}(9,16)=25+49=74$, but $d_{1}(4,16)=36$, it is not the case that $d_{1}(4,9)+d_{1}(9,16)\leq d_{1}(4,16)$, so $d_{1}$ is not a norm.

Comment: But I want to show with convexity, is it possible?

Comment: @Jason you can scale user284331's example. $\left(\frac{4}{25}, \frac{9}{25}\right)$ etc..

Comment: but I want to show that it is convex by definition, is it  possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, observe that $X$ is a vector space with norm $\phi$, then the closed unit ball in $(X,\phi)$ is convex. Indeed, this follows from triangle inequality of $\phi$.

Now, choose $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$. Clearly $x,y$ are elements of the closed unit ball since $d_1(x)=d_1(y)=1$. However, if we choose $\mu=0.5$, then
$$d_1(\mu x + (1-\mu)y) = d_1(0.5x+0.5y) = \left(\sqrt{0.5}+\sqrt{0.5}\right)^2 = \left(2\sqrt{0.5}\right)^2 = 2>1.$$
This shows that $0.5x+0.5y$ is not an element of the closed unit ball in $(X,d_1)$. It follows that $d_1$ is not a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, using contrapositive of the result in the first paragraph.